# API for making video conference calls in Iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is there any API to make video conferencing calls in Iphone sdk or any third party tools to make this.Guy's I need some documentation or tutorials to implement the video conferencing calls.

Anyone's suggestion will me much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Monish.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion by @Laurent Etiemble in this previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607130/video-calling-conference-api-for-iphone)

Take a look at the [iDoubs](http://code.google.com/p/idoubs/) project. It is a full feature SIP/IMS phone with various audio/video capabilities. Note that the project is under [GPL license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html).