# Video Calling/Conference API for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, video

Currently am doing project on Family Business. In that I need some video calling sort of thing.

Is there any API available for video conference (or) Any Open Source is available?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: There is no API but you can initiate a Facetime call with the following line [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"facetime://555112233"]];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [iDoubs](http://code.google.com/p/idoubs/) project. It is a full feature SIP/IMS phone with various audio/video capabilities. Note that the project is under [GPL license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html).

Comment: hi, note the license.. it's GPL because it uses x264 for the video encoding. Check out OpenTok, it could be useful